# Can't connect bluetooth headset to mac mini

Tags: wifi, bluetooth

I just bought sony ch500 wireless bluetooth headset and I can't pair it with my mac mini. I was able to pair it with my android phone though. What could be the problem? The bluetooth menu doesn't show my headset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out that because I paired it with my phone, it was not in the pairing mode anymore. So, I held the power button for 10 seconds or so and it went into the pairing mode again and I was able to see it in my bluetooth menu.

Answer (score 0):

There’s not much you can do but restart and remove any 2.4 ghz interference sources.

iOS has some tips like making sure the device is reset. If it’s paired with your android, it might not broadcast it’s looking to pair with your Mac.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201205